# shell script + one single syntax command in the script to send errors to log

Tags: ksh

I have the `test.ksh` script

my question if it possible to define in the first of the script that all standard errors will go to `/tmp/errlog` file in place to put `2>/tmp/errlog` after each command etc

second do not suggest  the option to put the `./test.ksh 2>/tmp/errlog` isn't relevant

lida

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `exec 2> /tmp/error.log`.

From the [manual](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh-man.html#Built-in%20Commands):

**exec** [  **-c**  ] [  **-a** *name*   ] [  *arg*  . . .  ]

If
*arg* 
is given,
the command specified by
the arguments is executed in place of this shell
without creating a new process.
The
**-c**
option causes the environment to be cleared before applying
variable assignments associated with the
**exec**
invocation.
The
**-a**
option
causes
*name* 
rather than the first
*arg*,
to become

**argv[0]**
for the new process.
Input/output arguments may appear and
affect the current process.
If
*arg* 
is not given,
the effect of this command is to
modify file descriptors
as prescribed by the input/output redirection list.
In this case,
any file descriptor numbers greater than 2 that are
opened with this mechanism are closed when invoking
another program.